# UTL_FILE. FOPEN and ora-06502

Tags: plsql, utl-file

I have to read a big file line by line, usually more than 400 kb, change some values and write the file changed in another file.

My problema now is that I'm having a ora-06502 in the fopen  .... the code is like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pfichero (pnomficheroorigen in VARCHAR2, 
    pnomficherodestino in varchar2) AS
  
    vcdclasnm varchar2(2) := '01';
    vhabilitacion_destino varchar2(3) := 'PRU';
    v_filehandleorigen UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    v_filehandledestino UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    v_nomficheroorigen VARCHAR2(50) := pnomficheroorigen;
    v_nomficherodestino VARCHAR2(50) := pnomficherodestino;
    v_linea varchar2(32767);
    vlineadestino varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('traza 0: '||v_nomficheroorigen);
    v_filehandleorigen  := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_DESA',v_nomficheroorigen,'R',32767);
    dbms_output.put_line ('traza 1');
    v_filehandledestino := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_DESA',v_nomficherodestino,'W',32767);
```

The error ocurrs on the line "v_filehandleorigen  := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_DESA',v_nomficheroorigen,'R',32767);".

Can anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the whole error message?

Comment: Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.
INICIO
traza 0: Carga2b.dat
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : error de conversión de carácter a número numérico o de valor

Comment: At the end it was the error was invalid operation. Appeared when I uncommented the exception block. And I don't understand it, because one of the exceptions was WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
     Rollback;
     verror: = sqlerrm;
dbms_output.put_line (verror);
utl_file.fclose_all;
Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and complete code would help a lot.